# RecyclerView and Item Position and click on particular item

Tags: android-recyclerview, adapter, onclicklistener

This is the interface of my application, my question is, if I click on "video lecture" then it should go to Video Lecture Activity and if i click on "Detail Notes" then it should go in Detail Notes Activity. Similarly, i want to do with all recyclerView items.

[image]

This is my Adapter code

```js
package com.example.motionofknowledge;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.motionofknowledge.databinding.ActivityMaterialsBinding;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Materials extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMaterialsBinding binding;
    FirebaseFirestore database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMaterialsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        String head = getIntent().getStringExtra("subName");

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.headingMat);
        textView.setText(new String(head));

        database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        ArrayList<MatModel> materials = new ArrayList<>();
        MatAdapter adapter = new MatAdapter(this,materials);

        String subId = getIntent().getStringExtra("subId");

        database.collection("subjects")
                .document(subId)
                .collection("mat")
                .orderBy("index")

                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                        materials.clear();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot:value.getDocuments()){
                            MatModel model = snapshot.toObject(MatModel.class);
                            model.setMatId(snapshot.getId());
                            materials.add(model);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

        binding.matList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        binding.matList.setAdapter(adapter);


        binding.matHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Materials.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is my adapter code

```js
package com.example.motionofknowledge;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MatAdapter.MatViewHolder>{


    Context context;
    ArrayList<MatModel> matModels;

    public MatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MatModel> matModels){
        this.context = context;
        this.matModels = matModels;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_category,null);

        return new MatViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MatViewHolder holder, int position) {

        MatModel model = matModels.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(model.getMatName());
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(model.getMatImage())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,Chapters.class);
                intent.putExtra("matId",model.getMatId());
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return matModels.size();
    }

    public class MatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        public MatViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please support me to solve this query

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your adapter code, but your activity code. Anyway: I understand that you have a recyclerView with different kind of items in it (Video Lecture, Detail Notes, and more). Depending on which item the user clicks, you want to do different things.

This is done by using the `onBindViewHolder` method in your `MatAdapter`. This method does not only bind the data to the UI layout, but it should also be used to bind a click listener to the UI layout.

If you have only a few items in your RecyclerView, you could use the `getItem(position)` method of your adapter to find out what specific item you are dealing with within `onBindViewHolder`. As soon as you know what kind of item the Adapter wants to bind, you can set the according click listener.

See this suggestion:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = null

        if (model.type == VIDEO) {
            intent = new Intent(context,Video.class);
        } else if (model.type == DETAILS) {
            intent = new Intent(context,Details.class);
        } else {
          ...
        }
    
        intent.putExtra("matId",model.getMatId());
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

- `model` is the current `MatModel` that you want to bind.
- `model.type` is any way to distinguish the different items. I do not know the details of the `MatModel` class, but you somehow need to be able to distinguish the different models, of course.

Comment: Sir please read my adapter code also and suggest how to implement this method in my app

Comment: @Ravi chill :) stackoverflow is not a helpcenter where people wait for your reaction to immediately get back at you ;) I added some code that you can use in your adapter.

Comment: @mutezenflo sir, i have done all this but it is still showing error

Comment: @mutezenflo : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Intent.putExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: well this is basic programming now. Read the error message: Your intent object is still null. So none of the if-branches was "true". For that I cannot help you, because I do not know what Activities you want to start for each if-branch.